# AWS AMI - fail to create json import file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I created a bucket in Amazon S3, uploaded my FreePBX.ova, and created permissions, etc. When I run this command:

```
aws ec2 import-image --cli-input-json "{\"Description\":\"freepbx\", \"DiskContainers\":[{\"Description\":\"freepbx\",\"UserBucket\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"itbucket\",\"S3Key\":\"FreePBX.ova\"}}]}"
```

I get:

```
Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: Extra data: line 1 column 135 - line 1 column 136 (char 134 - 135)
JSON received: {"Description":"freepbx", "DiskContainers":[{"Description":"freepbx","UserBucket":{"S3Bucket":"itbucket","S3Key":"FreePBX.ova"}}]}?
```

And I can't continue the process. I tried to Google it with no results.
What is wrong with this command? How can I solve it?

Comment: Re-type that command line by hand -- don't copy/paste. It looks like you have something non-printable or an invalid character that visually resembles the correct value getting in there.

Comment: You are missing the [ ] characters around \"S3Bucket\":\"itbucket\", \"S3Key\":\"FreePBX.ova\"